# Geocoder widget find() method does nothing

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geocoding

According to https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geocoder-amd.html#find the geocoder widget has a method "find" which seems to be a manual way of forcing the widget to start the geocode.

I put this method into one of the esri samples but it never actually does anything.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shoe788/4zeLb/) of the Esri sample code plus the line `geocoder.find()`

My intent here is that I want to be able to have an address be automatically located to when the user loads the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find method only executes a query to the geocode service and doesn't select features that get returned.

In order to mimic the behavior of the widget search I had to change `geocoder.find()` to use the `select` method on the widget object

```
all([geocoder.find()]).then(function(results){
    geocoder.select(results[0].results[0]);
});
```